# iptables packet count for nat table for ACCEPT target is always remained 0

Tags: linux, iptables

iptables packet count for nat table for ACCEPT target is always remained 0.

I have created a rule in IPTABLE for nat table and POSTROUTING chain  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT`, so that i could monitor the icmp packet going through this chain. After making ping request to other host, when i listed the iptables rules it show 0 packet count. Please share me where i am wrong.

Comment: Probably the `nat` table has no counting implemented.

Comment: Its not like that. If we use MASQUERADE target then it will show the count of all matched packet.

Comment: I suppose in the `nat` table only rules that "do something" will have actual counters then. Since `nat` is not supposed to be used for filtering `ACCEPT` might be considered a "n(o-)op". (More precisely, "do some NAT", I guess.)

Comment: ACCEPT is fine, in this table it still has the purpose of "return without processing further rules" (e.g. often used to add exceptions for the main NAT rules that follow).

Comment: What happens if you run `conntrack -D -p icmp` or even `conntrack -F`? One special thing about the nat table is that it only triggers for the *first* packet of each flow.

Comment: What I meant was, from the NAT perspective, that "purpose" means "do nothing" too.

Comment: i also feel like that NAT is not doing anything for ACCEPT target. Can anyone have supporting reference for it.